# pyramid.config.Configurator() does not work with 'with' context manager

Tags: pyramid

Is trying the quick start guide in pyramid website: https://trypyramid.com

```
from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server
from pyramid.config import Configurator
from pyramid.request import Response

def hello_world(request):
    return Response('Hello World')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with Configurator() as config:
        config.add_route('hello','/')
        config.add_view(hello_world, route_name='hello')
        app = config.make_wsgi_app()

    server = make_server('0.0.0.0',6543,app)
```

Gives the following error:

```
/anaconda3/bin/python /Users/user1/Desktop/play/pyramid_play/tut_1/exp1.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user1/Desktop/play/pyramid_play/tut_1/exp1.py", line 12, in <module>
    with Configurator() as config:
AttributeError: __enter__

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Did you follow the helpful [installation instructions](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/install.html) mentioned on that page?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Steve Piercy. This was an installation problem. I let pycharm install Pyramid while creating the project. pycharm used conda to install the package, which installed v1.5.7 (latest on conda repos) instead of the 1.9.1 (current version).
I installed pip to install the latest version which fixed the issue.